# How can WSL Python correctly decode Unicode characters coming from the output of a PowerShell subprocess?

Tags: python, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, decode

I am running python natively installed in WSL ubuntu that runs a powershell to  get a list of files in serveral folders and their creation time. like this

```
command = r''' powershell.exe -Command "(Get-ChildItem -Path 'folder_path' -File -Recurse  | Where-Object { \$_.CreationTime.AddSeconds(-\$_.CreationTime.Seconds) -ge \$(\$(get-date).AddMinutes(-5).AddSeconds(-\$(get-date).Second) )}).FullName" '''

result = subprocess.run(
  command, shell=True, check=True,
  capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='iso-8859-7'
)
```

The problem is that some characters in that file name are in Greek and no matter what i try they are not displaying correctly in result.stdout

i tried several encodings, like 'iso-8859-7', 'iso-8859-1', 'latin-1' all failed to display the greek characters correctly. utf8 displays this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 45: invalid continuation byte.

Comment: I'd try to help with this, or at least reproduce it, but can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I can try?

Comment: Make sure you set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` in PowerShell to the same

Comment: Are either or both Python and PowerShell run natively in WSL, or via `.exe` files on the host? Please clarify by directly updating your question.